# Schema testing using Mocha Timeout Error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, testing, mocha.js, schema

This is my Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//INDEX PAGE SCHEMA
const IndexSchema = new Schema({
  bio: String
});
const IndexPageData = mongoose.model('indexpagedata', IndexSchema);
module.exports = IndexPageData;
```

this is my mocha code:

```
const assert = require('assert');
const mocha = require('mocha');
const MarioChar = require('../models/model');

// Describe our tests
describe('Saving records', function(){

  // Create tests
  it('Saves a record to the database', function(done){

var index = new IndexPageData({
  bio: 'Mario ENTER BIO HERE'
});

char.save().then(function(){
  assert(char.isNew === false);
  done();
});

});

});
```

`

Everytime I run this I get an error stating 
"     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves."

mongoDB is already running in the background so I don't know what could be causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two options.

1. add catch
2. set timeout

I usually insert both of them into my code.

```
// Add catch 
describe('Saving records', function(){
  // Create tests
  it('Saves a record to the database', function(done){

    var index = new IndexPageData({
        bio: 'Mario ENTER BIO HERE'
    });

    char.save().then(function(){
        assert(char.isNew === false);
        done();
    }).catch(done);
  });
});

// Add time out
describe('Saving records', function(){

  // Create tests
  it('Saves a record to the database', function(done){
    this.timeout(3000); // milli seconds
    var index = new IndexPageData({
        bio: 'Mario ENTER BIO HERE'
    });

    char.save().then(function(){
        assert(char.isNew === false);
        done();
    }).catch(done);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I added both catch and timeout as you said, and the error persists. It is telling me that "ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves." How can I ensure that done() is called?

Comment: I think your "done()" is never called by your logic. That mean is that the `char.save()` has never connected to mongo I guess. I think you should make sure `connect to mongo` first.

[mongoose connect](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html) Would you like to refer to this page